# AES GCM crypto library for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, aes

I'm going to develop a multi-platform application (iOS and Android) and I need to encrypt some data with AES GCM. Can you please tell me what are the libraries for both platform to do this?

I know that there is CommonCrypt for iOS but I don't know if it support GCM.

Answer (score 2):

Conceal https://github.com/facebook/conceal provides an API to encrypt data on android. It uses AES GCM under the hood

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Common Crypto header GCM mode is not available. The closest is CTR (kCCModeCTR) but that would take some research to see if it is available for AES. Interestingly `kCCModeCTR` does not have a @constant defined for it.

If you are just going to "encrypt some data", where data is not really a high speed communication stream just use CBC with PKCS7 Padding. If you need the authentication portion of GCM this won't meet your needs.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. Do you know if there is any other crypto library for iOS that supports GCM?

Comment: No. But you can use and "C" or "C++" code you can find. Interestingly Apple is using GCM for the keychain since ios5.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [Encryptor4j](https://github.com/martinwithaar/Encryptor4j). It's a small library for simplifying common encryption tasks in Java and Android. As its author I can vow for its ease of use and simplicity:

```
String message = "This string has been encrypted & decrypted using AES in Galois Counter Mode";
SecretKey secretKey = KeyFactory.AES.randomKey();
Encryptor encryptor = new Encryptor(secretKey, "AES/GCM/NoPadding", 16, 128);
byte[] encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(message.getBytes());
```

Just add the following line to your `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'org.encryptor4j:encryptor4j:0.1.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

- Themis

https://cocoapods.org/pods/themis

General purpose cryptographic library for storage and messaging for iOS (Swift, Obj-C), Android (Java, Kotlin), desktop Java, С/С++, Node.js, Python, Ruby, PHP, Go, Rust, WASM.